# android chips динамическим JSON

Tags: android

Привет всем. 
https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete мне нужна такая штука, но чтобы список пользователей получил с сервера в виде JSON данных. Потому что на сервере будут десятки тысяч пользователей. И ещё чтобы запрос отправлялся тогда, когда пользователь перестает печатать. Чтобы лишней нагрузки на сервер не было.